# Chef: No available formula with the name "httpd"

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

I am learning chef and I got stuck here while trying to install httpd package. I have a simple recipe to install httpd package on Mac OS. I installed ChefDK.

**webserver.rb**

```
package 'httpd'
```

when I run `chef-apply webserver.rb`, it throws errors:

```
    Mixlib::ShellOut::ShellCommandFailed
------------------------------------
Expected process to exit with [0], but received '1'
---- Begin output of brew info --json=v1 httpd ----
STDOUT: 
STDERR: Error: No available formula with the name "httpd"
---- End output of brew info --json=v1 httpd ----
Ran brew info --json=v1 httpd returned 1

Resource Declaration:
---------------------
# In webserver.rb

  1: package 'httpd'

Compiled Resource:
------------------
# Declared in webserver.rb:1:in `run_chef_recipe'

homebrew_package("httpd") do
  action [:install]
  retries 0
  retry_delay 2
  default_guard_interpreter :default
  package_name "httpd"
  declared_type :package
  cookbook_name "(chef-apply cookbook)"
  recipe_name "(chef-apply recipe)"
end
```

Can some one tell me what I missed here. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So let's walk through each piece of what you are doing:

`chef-apply` takes a single Chef recipe and runs it locally. That means everything that happens is on your Mac laptop.

This recipe uses a `package` resource to install a thing called `'httpd'`. Chef includes a bunch of providers for the `package` resource, so on Ubuntu it uses APT, on CentOS it uses YUM, and on OS X it uses Homebrew (i.e. `brew install`).

Before it installs the package, Chef checks to see if it is already installed and gathers other details on the package. For Homebrew, it uses `brew info` for this. So you end up with the command `brew info httpd`, give or take the JSON output format argument to make it easier to parse. Homebrew has no package (formula) named `'httpd'` so it returns an error, which Chef then raises up the chain.

At a deeper level, Homebrew doesn't package Apache (what I presume you are trying to install) because it comes by default in OS X. Even if it did, most packaging systems call it `apache2`. Only RHEL/CentOS derivatives call the package `httpd` still.

Comment: thanks @coderanger, chef tutorial was not clear. I assumed that this is abstracted for all the platforms.

Comment: The level of abstraction is just which underlying package system to use, not the name/usage of packages in general. There is an `httpd` community cookbook you can use which provides a more complete abstraction for "install Apache2 on my system".